# Delete rows based on two conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe df that looks like:

```
    0   1   2   3
0   x   a       
1   x   b       
2   x   c       
3   x   a       
4   x   b       
5   x   c       
6   y   a       
7   y   b       
8   y   c       
9   z   a       
10  z   b       
11  z   c       
12  z   a       
13  z   b       
14  z   c
```

I want to delete rows where
`df[1]=="c" AND df[0]==df[0].shift(-1)`

However I am not able to combine these 2 conditions.
Here is my code:

```
m1 = (df[df[0].eq(df[0].shift(-1))])
m2 = (df[df[1].eq("x")])

df[~(m1 & m2)]
```

I get error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

If I try

```
df[~(m1 and m2)]
```

I get error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: what is AccessWestWinterBlend

Comment: Should've just been "df" I changed the dataframe name to make it more common

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
m1 = df[0].eq(df[0].shift(-1))
m2 = df[1].eq("x")

df[~(m1 & m2)]
```

Comment: I edited my question. That's what my code actually looks like already and I get the errors I posted.

Comment: @Mitch take another look, my code is still different than yours :-).

Answer (score 0):

You should replace *AND* in your condition with *&*.

To drop your "not-wanted" rows, retrieve rows not meeting your condition
and save under *df*:

```
df = df[~((df[1] == 'c') & (df[0] == df[0].shift(-1)))]
```

The result is:

```
    0  1
0   x  a
1   x  b
3   x  a
4   x  b
5   x  c
6   y  a
7   y  b
8   y  c
9   z  a
10  z  b
12  z  a
13  z  b
14  z  c
```

(rows with index == *2* and *11* dropped).